# Centering elements in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Does the jQuery Mobile framework have a way of centering elements, specifically buttons? It looks like it defaults to left-aligning everything and I can't find a way (within the framework) to do this.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

jQuery Mobile doesn't seem to have a css class to center elements (I searched through its css).

But you can write your own additional css.

Try creating your own:

```
.center-button{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

example HTML:

```
<div data-role="button" class="center-button">button text</div>
```

and see what happens. You might need to set text-align to center in the wrapping tag, so this might work better:

```
.center-wrapper{
  text-align: center;
}
.center-wrapper * {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

example HTML:

```
<div class="center-wrapper">
  <div data-role="button">button text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've just found setting margins won't centre jQuery Mobile inline buttons - for those you'd probably have to use the .center-wrapper class.

Comment: Inline buttons are inline ;) The name suggests CSS display:inline which won't work like that. But you probably saved some people some time with this comment.

Comment: May I ask you to add the HTML code sample to have the "whole" stuff? Thank you very much!

Comment: I have added HTML examples, but one can use the classes from this answer with dozens of different tags. And examples obviously assume that something else was done with the buttons, as an ordinary block button has `width:auto` so it takes full width.

Comment: ` .csstag { text-align  :  center !important; } `

Answer (score 14):

An overkill approach: in inline css in the div did the trick:

```
style="margin:0 auto;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
align:center;
text-align:center;"
```

Centers like a charm!

Comment: To borrow from @andufo: always separate content and style. always.

Answer (score 3):

In the situation where you are NOT going to use this over and over (i.e. not needed in your style sheet), inline style statements usually work anywhere they would work inyour style sheet. E.g:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align:center;">
```

Comment: always separate content and style. always.

Answer (score 2):

The best option would be to put any element you want to be centered in a `div` like this:

> ```
>         <div class="center">
>             <img src="images/logo.png" />
>         </div>
> ```

and css or inline style:

> ```
> .center {  
>       text-align:center  
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I had found problems with some of the other methods mentioned here. Another way to do it would be to use layout grid B, and put your content in block b, and leave blocks a and c empty.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.2/docs/content/content-grids.html

```html
<div class="ui-grid-b">
 <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
 <div class="ui-block-b">Your Content Here</div>
 <div class="ui-block-c"></div>
</div><!-- /grid-b -->
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers alone worked for me. I had to combine them. (Maybe it is because I'm using a "button" tag and not a link typed as a button?)

In the HTML:

```
<div class="center-wrapper"><button type="submit" data-theme="b">Login</button></div>
```

In the CSS:

```
.center-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    align:center;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the button an anchor element, and put it in a paragraph with the attribute:

```
align='center'
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To have them centered correctly and only for the items inside the wrapper .center-wrapper use this. ( all options combined should work cross browser ) if not please post a reply here!

```
.center-wrapper .ui-btn-text {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

HTML

```
<section id="wrapper">
    <div data-role="page">
    </div>
</section>
```

Css

```
#wrapper { 
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1239px;
    height:1022px;
    background:#ffffff;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust as your requirement

```
   .ui-btn{
      margin:0.5em 10px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but it's very brief. Hopefully it is obvious to viewers that this is a CSS style sheet edit.