# How do I center a set of JQuery Mobile radio buttons in the viewport?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova, radio-button, centering

I'm making an app using JQuery Mobile on top of PhoneGap (Cordova). I used Codiqa to come up with a wireframe for my UI. It looks OK so far, but the group of radio buttons I'm going to use to change views with wasn't centred - it was off to the left by about 25px on a WVGA800-sized webkit browser. When scaled to a tablet shape, the group got further and further from the centre of the viewport.

Here's a jsFiddle link to my project with the problem unfixed - http://jsfiddle.net/jaspermogg/sahXy/1/

Here's a jsFiddle link to my project as fixed by me - http://jsfiddle.net/jaspermogg/NvMsK

I came up with a solution using JQuery, but I'm inexperienced and don't know which event to fire on.

When I load the UI in Webkit, it renders the UI pre-script, before refreshing after <1s to a post-script state. This looks lame. I have my script set up to run on `$(window).load`.

Questions:

1. What event should I be looking for, and could you show me how to implement that?
2. Is my script in the right place - should it be inside the page, the way it is, or outside? Or in `head` even?
3. It feels really stupid to be doing this with JQ - surely there's a way to do this with CSS?

Thanks in advance for any help offered! Cheers!

Comment: i have fixed the center alignment with box model. Although this is still not elegant solution (i m not that good with css) http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/sahXy/3/

Comment: this post summarizes atleast the required solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329866/centering-elements-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: @dhaval Thanks, that's great. What I'd really like to do though is find the width that I need to set the div to before it displays. Your solution is a few px off, because you've given box-center a static width. Surely on different devices the px width required will differ, and that'll break the page?

Comment: @dhaval actually, I guess that's what I should do - have them invisible when the page loads, find the width required, set it and make visible. You, sir, are a genius ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I answered my own question in the comments above, so gonna formalise it by accepting my answer.

What I did in the end was -

(1) Set the radio button-containing div to `visibility: hidden` in the CSS.

(2) Find the widths of each radio button and add them together.

(3) Set the width of the radio button-containing div to the total width.

(4) Chain a change of the visibility property onto (3).

The CSS has to be set up like this -

```
#viewselector{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The code to do (1) to (4) is as follows -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var idealwidth = 0

    $(".ui-radio").each(function(){
        idealwidth = idealwidth + $(this).width();
    });

    $("#viewselector").width(idealwidth).css('visibility','visible');

});
```

Hope this helps someone!