# Center elements within div

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Is it good convention to center elements using `text-align: center`?
Why can't I centre a textbox using the same `text-align: center`?

jsFiddles: [Div with buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/M9Mnz/8/) &  [Textarea](http://jsfiddle.net/M9Mnz/14)

Comment: I've also found [this][1] method to work well.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4396545/503550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is a good convention - that why `text-align: center` was made for

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/M9Mnz/9/)

Comment: it happens because in `jquery.mobile.css` you have a rule that overwrites this one. It says `textarea.ui-input-text { ... margin:  .5em 0 }`.. If you counter-overwrite it then it will work - http://jsfiddle.net/M9Mnz/17/  Note that this rule exists for inputs and textareas only. That's why all the text, buttons etc. are centered with `text-align`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the style:

```
text-align:center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M9Mnz/10/

Answer (score 1):

To center align a text-area, you have to style it as `display:block;`, since textareas are inline elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/M9Mnz/18/