# Centering Text within JQuery Mobile via CSS

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am working on building an app with JQuery Mobile. My app will display a message at the top of the page below the header. I want to use the built in styling mechanisms. Currently, I have the following:

```
<div data-role="content">   
  <ul data-role="listview"> 
    <li data-role="list-divider"><span id="dynamicLabel">Loading</span></li>
  </ul><br />
</div>
```

How do I horizontally center the content displayed by `dynamicLabel`? No matter what I do, the text "Loading" is always aligned to the left. I've tried text-align:center, and margin-left:auto with margin-right:auto. No luck though.

Thank you for any insights you can provide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering elements in jQuery Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329866/centering-elements-in-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text-align:center;` to the parent `<li>`, not the `<span>`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/UmJ49/1/)

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in the JQuery Mobile CSS? I'm trying to figure out how the classes map to the various UI elements. Thank you!

Comment: After looking through the [base CSS](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css), I can safely say that there's no specific centered class, you will have to edit your css to include the `.centered { text-align:center; }`. It will be easier.