# Align Image Center Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, image, mobile, alignment, center

I have a panel in jquery mobile which looks like this:

[image]

I want the logo to be centered, however the following code is not working:

HTML

```
<div class="panel-content">
    <img src="images/logo.png" class="logopanel" width="15%" length="15%" align="center">
    <ul data-role="listview">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering elements in jQuery Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329866/centering-elements-in-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set .panel-content to text-align: center;

Comment: you are a gift from heaven